# Async task in public static method returns null

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

So I have an Async task that i have placed inside a public static method to avoid hanging the UI thread (as it does network calls) while still be able to call it from several parts of my application. The Async task works sucessfully and returns a JSONOBJECT (I have logged parts of my code to confirm this). However  the Problem is since am using a public static method,it should have a return type (that in may case should return the JSONOBJECT) but it always returns null..How can i re write my code for it to be able to return the JSONOBJECT fetched by my Async task. Code below.

```
public class JSONmethod {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static String res = "";
    static JSONObject jArray = null;
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(final String url){


    new AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();



    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }


    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            res=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    Log.i("Result BG ", res);
    try{

        jArray = new JSONObject(res);            
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return jArray; //at this point the JSONOBJECT has been fetched

     }



    }.execute();
    return jArray;  //Always null
 }
```

}

Comment: of course it's null. the doInBackground is called much after getJSONfromURL has returned.

Answer (score 4):

If your method is supposed to be asynchronous then it cannot return the JSON result right now...

What you can do is provide a callback to your async task which will be called when result is available:

```
    public class JSONmethod {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static String res = "";
    static JSONObject jArray = null;

    public static interface JSONCallback {
        public void onResult(JSONObject result);
    }

    public static void getJSONfromURL(final String url, final JSONCallback callback) {

        new AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag",
                            "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                }

                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    res = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag",
                            "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
                Log.i("Result BG ", res);
                try {

                    jArray = new JSONObject(res);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                callback.onResult(jArray);

                return jArray; // at this point the JSONOBJECT has been
                                // fetched

            }

        }.execute();
    }
}
```

And you would use it like that:

```
    JSONmethod.getJSONfromURL(url, new JSONCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(JSONObject result) {
            // Do whatever you want with the result
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The basis around an asynchronous task is that you will not get its result immediately after calling the method as a return value.

Your call (static or not) will only execute the procedure to create the task (w/o executing it!) and return immediately. The system may not execute the real task process code immediately (maybe there are some previous tasks on the queue, etc). Once it finishes the AsyncTask.doInBackground() method, and after calling AsyncTask.onPostExecute(), the task will finish. It will not call to any of yours methods by default. It's your responsability to do whatever you need to update the  UI on the AsyncTask.onPostExecute() method.

Comment: +1. The good way would be indeed to use your result in `onPostExecute()` to update the UI

Comment: @fiddler I tried using    onPostExecute() but it never gets called. I found that very weird. Let me try your earlier method and see if it works

Comment: @fiddler       I just tried using your solution but its still not working,the result returned is still null,the JSONOBJECT is not returned

Comment: You need to understand that your `getJSONfromURL` CANNOT return the JSON object directly because it's gonna be computed in background. That's the whole point of providing a callback which will receive the JSON data later when it is available